# How to divide expandable listview in 2 section with group header using separator

Tags: android, listview

I am using expandable listview to get sub-menu on click of menu. I want to create two different section in expandable listview exactly like menu using separator.

I am using -
MainActivity 
ExpandableListAdapter 
listheader 
list_submenu

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please provide code, what you have tried and where you have failed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend you migrate to recyclerView cause nobody use ListView nowadays.

If I get you right, you need something like [BigNerdRanch's ExpandableRecycler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html) or [expandable recycler view](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view).
This is 2 library, which very easy to use in your app. In some of projects, we used expandableRecycler from the Big Nerd Ranch. Easy, fast, and comfortable. Second one, didn`t try yet.

To divide views with separator, you might be want to use [DividerItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html) from support lib.
If, for some reason you still want to use listView - you can try [tutorial here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Regards.